# How do i manipulate the data templates inside listbox in uwp

Tags: xaml, uwp

I am making a chat application using XAML in UWP.The side panel is consisting of users. like this.

[image]

Everything is in Listbox in which I have this template that consists **one ellipse** as a circle which is like **an indicator**,**one user image**,**textblocks** and one toggle switch.I have to give states to the toggle switch in on the state it should change the green color of circle and make it red.

I want to give this functionality in code c# in MainPage.cs. I made the object of toggle in toggled Event Handler but I am not able to access the other elements inside the data template like ellispse,textblock.
What is the other alternative way of doing this?

***NOTE***: It has to be in listbox because I want to use the same template for every user.

Comment: You Can Bind property of element inside your list box, so  you can update it

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this would be to use data binding.

You would define a `ViewModel` class for the item, which would contain a `bool` property and would react to the toggling of the switch in the setter or have a `Command` which you would execute when the state event changes using behaviors.

If you really want the code as a event handler on main page, you have some options. To get the item associated with the toggle, you can use its `DataContext` property and cast it to the data type you are using. Alternatively, you can use `Visual Tree Extesnions` provided by the [UWP Community Toolkit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwpcommunitytoolkit/extensions/visualtree). This enables you to find the parent (probably `Grid`) where you store all the item controls and then manually find the user image, `TextBlock`, etc.

Comment: @user9180315 If this has resolved your issue, please consider accepting the answer as solution so that the question is resolved.